# How to return List<String> or String in Spring Data rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data rest for my application.

I am using following method in my repository.

```
public interface TestRepository() extends BaseRepository<TestTerm, Integer>{
    @Query("select distinct tt.term from TestTerm")
        List<String> findDistinctTerm();
}
```

When I execute the above method. I am getting following error

```
PersistentEntity must not be null
```

Question related to [Spring Data Rest (SDR ) bug? Persistent Entity Must not be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538426/spring-data-rest-sdr-bug-persistent-entity-must-not-be-null/33575327#comment67824619_33575327)

How can I resolve this ?

Do I have to write separate implementation for this ? If so Anyone provide me example for this ?

**Update:-**

I have tried like this

Method 1:-

```
@Query("select DISTINCT term from ForbiddenTerm")
List<TestTerm> findDistinctByTerm();
```

Error:-

{
  "cause": null,
  "message": "PersistentEntity must not be null!"
}

Method 2:-

```
List<TestTerm> findDistinctByTerm();
```

Error:-

```
    ... 154 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'forbiddenTermRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 175 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'forbiddenTermRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: You can not (directly ) with SDR since it can only return registered entity of  type 'TestTerm'. you need to declare another controller that uses this repository.

Comment: You don't need a separate implementation. By the way, are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: try `@Query("select distinct tt.term from TestTerm tt")` or do : `@Query("select distinct tt from TestTerm tt")` and return a list of `TestTerm` entities and then put all terms in a List

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of your interface like this:

```
@Repository
public interface TestTermRepository() extends BaseRepository<TestTerm, Integer>{
@Query("select distinct tt.term from TestTerm")
    List<String> findDistinctTerm();
}
```

**You also need to add the @Repository annotation**

Comment: have you changed the name of the interface?

Comment: what exception are you getting now? can you post it?

Comment: My error is below{
  "cause": null,
  "message": "PersistentEntity must not be null!"
}

Comment: Why would changing the name of the interface make any difference?

Comment: You also need to add the @Repository annotation

Comment: I have added @Repository annotation. Still same error as "PersistentEntity must not be null"

Comment: Something is probably wrong with your configuration. Show your code on how did you configured Spring data.